# how can i implementing on the fly filtering for rad grid Telerik component?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm using a [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) component  rad grid in my  web page, I want  have  on the fly filtering like this [on the fly filtering example](http://www.datatables.net/)

When user type a text in the above text-box  can see real-time changing in grid view.Rad grid has a filtering for each column.
But i want to filter all column by one text box at the top of my grid.

**My question are:**

1. How do can i implement such this filtering in rad grid Telerik?
2. Is it good using filter expansion?
3. Can i use java script function for this work by Rad grid control ?

Comment: see this link http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/trying-to-filter-a-radgrid-with-javascript.aspx